# Creating a new String Array from another

Tags: vba, excel

I have an array of integers (dfArray) and would like to create a new second String array which consists of the integers and appending "G" to the beginning. What's the best way to go about this? I was thinking of For Each but couldn't get it to work. Thanks in advance.

```
Set dfArray = [dff]
Set dfArray2 = ["G" & dff]  'incorrect but you get the idea?
```

Comment: what is [dff] ?

Comment: You don't **set** arrays; you **assign** them.

Comment: [dff] is a Range containing text numbers: 0001, 0002, 0007 etc. 


I am able to convert each Range to an Integer but unable to access it outside the scope. I think I've learnt that this can't be done using For loops. 


I'll take a step back so you can understand what I'm trying to do:


`Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(dfArray2)` 


I want to find the maximum value within this Range however; the Range values are stored as text in the workbook (this must be stored as text).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim dfArray() As Variant
Dim dfArray2() As String

dfArray = [dff].Value

ReDim dfArray2(UBound(dfArray)) As String

Dim i As Double

For i = 1 To UBound(dfArray) Step 1
    dfArray2(i) = "G" & dfArray(i, 1)
Next i
```

Anyways, from my personal point of view, I don't like to asign a complete Range into Array, only if needed. I prefer to loop using Lbound or Ubound and control the array all the time. To asign a range into an Array, you need the Array variable to be Variant type, and also, you can't use Preserve easily. Check this question for more info

[Issues about Variant Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38255666/9199828)

Comment: Your response solved my problem and has got me to better understand vba arrays. Cheers!!